# When can function not be redefined in init.el?

Tags: init-file, gnus

To solve a problem with the Gnus' IMAP search in Exchange folders with Emacs 28.2, I have the modified piece of code from `gnus-search.el` below.  However, if I add this to my `init.el` on starting Emacs I get the error that `gnus-search-imap` is undefined.  On the other hand, if I comment out the code, restart Emacs, start Gnus, try searching in an Exchange folder (which without the modified code always returns no result) and **then** evaluate the modified code, I get no error.

So can I put the code in my `init.el` somehow or do I just have to patch `gnus-search.el`?  If the later, why is this the case?

```
(cl-defmethod gnus-search-imap-search-command ((engine gnus-search-imap)
                         (query string))
  "Create the IMAP search command for QUERY.
Currently takes into account support for the LITERAL+ capability.
Other capabilities could be tested here."
  (with-slots (literal-plus) engine
    (when (and literal-plus
         (string-match-p "\n" query))
    (setq query (split-string query "\n")))
    (cond
     ((consp query)
    ;; We're not really streaming, just need to prevent
    ;; `nnimap-send-command' from waiting for a response.
    (let* ((nnimap-streaming t)
           (call
        (nnimap-send-command
         "UID SEARCH CHARSET UTF-8 %s"
         (pop query))))
      (dolist (l query)
        (process-send-string (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) l)
        (process-send-string (get-buffer-process (current-buffer))
                 (if (nnimap-newlinep nnimap-object)
                     "\n"
                   "\r\n")))
      (nnimap-get-response call)))
     (t (nnimap-command "UID SEARCH %s" query)))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So can I put the code in my init.el somehow

You can, but at minimum you need to ensure that Emacs doesn't try to *evaluate* your modified code before either:

- any prerequisites of that code have been defined
- the original function is loaded (which would simply clobber your definition)

The typical solution to both things is to establish which library defines the original function, and arrange for your code to be evaluated after that library has been loaded, and you can do that by wrapping the whole definition in the form like so:

```el
(with-eval-after-load "gnus-search"
  (cl-defmethod gnus-search-imap-search-command ...))
```

N.b. <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `gnus-search-imap-search-command` will tell you that `gnus-search.el` is the library in question, which gives us the `"gnus-search"` value.

This ensures that everything required by the original method is now defined, and (because the original method has been defined) that *your* definition will clobber it, rather than the other way around.